# Django, using current user id in model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, backend

I am not really familiar with Python or Django but I'm starting to build a web application using Django as backend.

I have some models with a field `filler`. This field was filled by the user and its value is an `id` of a `user`.

Now, I would like to automatically set its value to the currently logged in user.

From what I read it can be done by using the `save_model` method but I can't manage to make it work. (**Edit:** I'm not trying to set the value through the admin interface, so that's probably not what I'm looking for)

Here is what I got :

In models.py :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    CRITICITIES = (
        ('MAND', 'Mandatory to do the task'),
        ('HCHR', 'Not Mandatory but High Impact / High Risk Impact'),
        ('HCLR', 'Not Mandatory but High Impact / Low Risk Impact'),
        ('LCHR', 'Not Mandatory but Low Impact / High Risk Impact'),
        ('LCLR', 'Not Mandatory but Low Impact / Low Risk Impact'),
    )

    DOWNTIME = (
        ('3+', '> 3 Days'),
        ('1-3', '1 to 3 Days'),
        ('0.5-1', '1/2 to 1 Day'),
        ('0.5-', '<1/2 Day')
    )

    filler = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    user_departments = models.ManyToManyField('Department', related_name='+')
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', blank=False)
    processes = models.ManyToManyField('Process')
    functions = models.ManyToManyField('Function')
    frameworks = models.ManyToManyField('Framework')
    valuechains = models.ManyToManyField('ValueChain')
    regions = models.ManyToManyField('Region')
    project_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    downtime_acceptance = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=DOWNTIME, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=False)
    criticity_detail = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CRITICITIES, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)  #TODO: remove
    inputs = models.ManyToManyField('InputOutput', related_name='+', blank=True)
    outputs = models.ManyToManyField('InputOutput', related_name='+', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_view_logs', 'Can view project logs'),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

In serializers.py

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    requests = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'filler', 'title', 'description', 'requests', 'products', 'processes', 'functions', 'frameworks',
                  'categories', 'password', 'project_path', 'regions', 'criticity_detail', 'comment', 'inputs',
                  'outputs', 'valuechains', 'user_departments')
```

In urls.py :

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
# Other irrelevant routes
# ...
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet)
projects_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'projects', lookup='project', trailing_slash=False)
projects_router.register(r'requests', ProjectRequestViewSet, base_name='project-requests')
router.register(r'requestcomments', RequestCommentViewSet)
router.register(r'requests', RequestViewSet)
requests_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'requests', lookup='request', trailing_slash=False)
requests_router.register(r'statuses', RequestStatusViewSet, base_name='request-statuses')
requests_router.register(r'comments', RequestCommentViewSet, base_name='request-comments')
requests_router.register(r'estimatedcosts', RequestEstimatedCostViewSet, base_name='request-estimatedcosts')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(projects_router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(requests_router.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^token-auth', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

And in views.py :

```
class ProjectViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows projects to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

For example, here we have the fields `created_at` and `updated_at` that are automatically posted with the proper value (the current date) each time a project is posted.
What I tried to achieve there is to do the same for the field `filler` with the current user id.

Comment: The `save_model` method is only called when saving a model through the Django admin. Since your error message includes `ProjectSerializer`, it sounds like you are not using the Django admin to edit the instance, so overriding `save_model` won't work. You need to show the code that you are using to update the instance using the API.

Comment: So far, I was sending the request (POST/PUT) from my front-end using angularjs. I'm still doing it but I removed the `filler` field from the sent object.

Comment: If you are making a post/put request, then you need to show the code that is handling that request. It isn't being handled by the Django admin, so the model admin isn't relevent.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make Django handle the `filler` field, just like it does for the `created_at` and `updated_at`. But I edited my question and added the js part handling the post request for a new project.

Comment: You need to show the *Django* code that handles the API request e.g. `/api/catalog/projects/<id>` -- it's not handled by the Django admin.

Comment: Do u mean the code interacting with the API ? If so, not sure where that is.  All I got in the catalog directory is a fixtures and migrations folders and the main .py files (models, serializers, urls, views, admin, __init__)

Comment: Please show the serializers, urls and views. You can remove the admin.py, because it's not the issue here.

Comment: Question edited to make these informations available

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you are doing the right thing in the admin. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods), exactly your usecase. If, however, you are saving the model from somewhere else, you might want to override the [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) method within the Model.